# how can I connect the SharePoint with the SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I'm a new in learning with SharePoint, and i knew only few things about it.
i have an SQL server database and I want to connect the SharePoint with this Database,i downloaded the " SharePoint Videos for the Essential Training" but there weren't any videos to show me how to connect with the sql server. Could any one show me how to do that please,

Comment: Do you want to set up Sharepoint itself? Or do you want to retrieve data from your database into a list in sharepoint? Please describe your problem in detail

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=794

Comment: thank you Serv for your response, I want to connect my sql server database to the sharepoint, not sitting up the sharepoint, i already have it.

Comment: thank you  Nagarajm i will check the link now, it locks helpful, thanks again.

Comment: i did check the link and it was helpful, but the problem is i have to create a list manualy for each table in the sqlserver data base, is there a way to creat the lists for all the tables once i connect to the data base ? @NagarajS

Comment: @Leanah_as since i am also  new to sharepoint..I does not have any idea for that.Sorry..